# Convert OpenCV stereorectify camera output to three.js camera

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl-es, three.js

I have calibrated my stereo cameras using OpenCV's stereoCalibrate() and rectified them using stereoRectify(). This is successful (cameras' epipolar lines correctly aligned and can obtain accurate 3D point locations from corresponding 2D point left/right pairs).

I'm now trying to use WebGL-based three.js to display the same 3D points in the same projection as I have in OpenCV. In other words, if I overlaid the calibrated and rectified 2D image from my left camera onto the three.js output, the three.js 3D points should visually align with where they are on the OpenCV 2D image. This could be used for augmented reality.

Just dealing with the left camera (camera 1):

stereoRectify() provides projection matrix P1 and rectification transform R1. Using only P1 I can convert a 3D point to the correct 2D screen position in OpenCV. However, I am having difficulty using P1 to get an equivalent camera.projectionMatrix in three.js.

I'm using the OpenCV camera matrix to OpenGL projection conversion suggested by Guillaume Noctua [here](https://blog.noctua-software.com/opencv-opengl-projection-matrix.html). I'm taking the camera matrix to be the top-left 3x3 of P1. That produces a three.js camera view that looks similar, but not quite aligned (camera appears rotated along all axis by a degree or so, with perhaps some other small but clearly erroneous distortions/translations). So I'm missing something. Do I need to use the rectification transform R1 somehow too? I've tried using it as a rotation matrix and rotating the three.js camera by this amount but it doesn't improve.

Any thoughts on using OpenCV's P1 and R1 matrix to make an equivalent camera view in three.js would be much appreciated.